# Preventing a user from creating table in H2

Tags: sql, h2

in H2 DBMS I want a user (which he is not admin by the way) to not be able to alter the database schema.
But surprisingly despite the fact I didn't grant this user the ability to create tables (I didn't use the SQL statement `grant alter any schema to u1` ) .This user was able to create but not able to drop or alter tables !!!!!!
Is there a way to revoke the ability of creating a table from a user in H2 DBMS ?
One more thing I want a user to be able to create user but not able to alter schema is this possible or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible currently.

Access rights in the H2 database are very basic currently. If you need more features, or course you could write the the H2 Google Group or write a patch.

Comment: I did notice that H2 is still basic and not mature enough for large scale applications

Comment: Let's say it is not ready yet for complex applications :-) It is still mainly used as an embedded database, and for testing, and in both cases only basic access rights management features are needed.

Answer (score 0):

For the last part, if he Is not admin he should not be doing anything with user management.
Can you provide more info about what permission you granted this user?

Comment: I want the user to be able to create a new user but not able to alter the DB schema in way